# NoAccessRuntimeException when testing a data source in WebLogic console

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I'm working on a J2EE application. Everything works if I use a local WebLogic instance, but if I deploy it to the remote server where it will ultimately need to run (WebLogic 10.3.3.0), the data source becomes inaccessible. I can bring up the first web page, but as soon as I press a button that triggers a database access, I get the following error in the browser:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{backing_admin.loginAction}: javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [PGY2].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'PGY2'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'PGY2'; nested exception is: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [PGY2].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'PGY2'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'PGY2'
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
    ...
```

If I go to the remote server's WebLogic console and try to test the data source, I get this error:

```
An unexpected exception has occurred processing your request

Message:    
Access not allowed for subject: principals=[wlm, AppTesters, Monitors], on ResourceType: JDBCDataSourceRuntime Action: execute, Target: testPool

Stack Trace:
weblogic.management.NoAccessRuntimeException: Access not allowed for subject: principals=[wlm, AppTesters, Monitors], on ResourceType: JDBCDataSourceRuntime Action: execute, Target: testPool
at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.sendReceive(ServerRequest.java:205)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:222)
at ...
```

What does this error mean, and what could cause it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the remote server has security policy defined. I am not sure though if the security has been defined globally or scope to just to specific JDBC data source.

You can log on to console if you have credentials and look at

> Home >Summary of JDBC Data Sources >
>   %your_data_source% >Roles >Policies
>
> > Roles

From the log I can see you authenticated with user "wlm". Check with the administrator on the security restrictions.

Comment: `Home > Summary of JDBC Data Sources` shows no data sources whatsoever. I can view my JDBC configuration in `Home > Summary of Deployments > <name of application> > PGY2`, and no roles/policies are defined there. The Credential Mappings tab has this error message: `[Management:141102]Subject: principals=[wlm, AppTesters, Monitors] does not have access to perform Admin actions.` If testing a data source is an admin action, then this would explain the second error, but not the first (why the application can't access the data source).

Comment: Is your JDBC resource application scoped? If not you must definitely see at least the JDBC data source in "Summary....". Can you check with simple client (outside of weblogic) code to lookup JDBC resource & execute SQL? From the above stack trace I can only see that some code is trying to "execute". The "Admin" action I believe you got it right.